# Get value from custom category attribute

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to get the value from a custom category attribute in Magento. The attribute is a select field and is been made with the install script below:

```
$this->startSetup();

$this->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'category_categorycolor', array(
    'group'         => 'General Information',
    'input'         => 'select',
    'type'          => 'varchar',
    'label'         => 'Categorie kleur',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 0,
    'user_defined'  => 1,
    'option'            => array (
                                    'value' => array('yellow' => array('Geel'),
                                                     'purple' => array('Paars'),
                                                     'blue' => array('Blauw'),
                                                     'red' => array('Rood'),
                                                     'orange' => array('Oranje'),
                                                     'green' => array('Groen'),
                                                     'darkblue' => array('Donkerblauw'),
                                                     'lightgreen' => array('Lichtgroen'),                                               
                                                )
                                ),
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));

$this->endSetup();
```

Unfortunately only getting numbers and not text value. I use this line to retrieve the value:

```
<?php $_category_categorycolor = $_category->getData('category_categorycolor'); if($_category_categorycolor): ?> <?php echo $_category_categorycolor; ?> <?php endif; ?>
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sollution is pretty messy (the only one I know of).

```
$opt = array(); // will contain all options in a $key => $value manner
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_category', 'category_categorycolor');
    if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
        $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
        foreach ($options as $o) {
            $opt[$o['value']] = $o['label'];
        }
    }

$categoryColorId = $_category->getData('category_categorycolor');
$categoryColorLabel = $opt[$categoryColorId];

// if you have problems, do a Zend_Debug::dump($opt); 
// - it should contain an array of all the options you added
```

Didn't test it out, let me know if it works or not.

PS: can't reply to your comment, not sure why. What does $opt contain ?

Comment: Hi Vlad. It contains the following:

array(8) {
  [11] => string(5) "Blauw"
  [15] => string(11) "Donkerblauw"
  [9] => string(4) "Geel"
  [14] => string(5) "Groen"
  [16] => string(10) "Lichtgroen"
  [13] => string(6) "Oranje"
  [10] => string(5) "Paars"
  [12] => string(4) "Rood"
}

Comment: Hi Vlad. My fault. Wrong echo :-) It's working with <?php echo $categoryColorLabel; ?>

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
$category_id = '10';
$attribute_code = 'category_categorycolor';
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);

echo $category->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($category);
```

Comment: Almost. I need the current category ID instead of a specific one.

Comment: `Mage::registry('current_category')` stores your current category

Answer (score 0):

The numbers you are getting back are the id's of each value in the dropdown.  You have to load the dropdown values too.

See the following page. It helped me understand this.

http://www.sharpdotinc.com/mdost/2009/04/06/magento-getting-product-attributes-values-and-labels/